# "Destroying" a function in PHP 5.2x

Tags: php, function, include, overriding, destroy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing a function at runtime in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120044/removing-a-function-at-runtime-in-php)

I have a script that is including different files while running. The files all contain a function with the same name. I only need the currently included to exist. Is there any way to enable dynamic file including, so it won't be causing Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function()?
In another words I need to either rename or remove the previous function.

The function is declared in a classical way function fn(){;}

Comment: are you still using procedural code?

Comment: what fluty probably meant to say is, you should go OO. it solves problems like this for you. let me know, if you need some good links to tutorials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120044/removing-a-function-at-runtime-in-php someone already asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than each file defining a top-level function with the same name, consider using a very simple OO structure:

Assuming you have something like this:

```
switch ( $some_condition )
{
    case 'normal':
    default:
        include_once 'normal_function.php';
    break;
    case 'special':
        include_once 'special_function.php';
    break;
    case 'secret':
        include_once 'secret_function.php';
    break;
}

do_the_action();
```

You could replace it with something like this:

```
switch ( $some_condition )
{
    case 'normal':
    default:
        include_once 'normal_class.php';
        $handler_object = new Normal_Class();
    break;
    case 'special':
        include_once 'special_class.php';
        $handler_object = new Special_Class();
    break;
    case 'secret':
        include_once 'secret_class.php';
        $handler_object = new Secret_Class();
    break;
}

$handler_object->do_the_action();
```

And then in each of the included files, instead of one function, you would define a class containing that function, like this:

```
class Normal_Class
{
    public function do_the_action()
    {
        // Implementation for normal case goes here 
    }
}
```

Not only does this solve your problem, it puts you on the road to learning other advanced/OO PHP techniques - autoloading the files so you don't have to specify `include_once` every time, defining hierarchies and interfaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!function_exists('myFunction')) {
    function myFunction() {
        ....
    }
}
```

will only define the first version of the function loaded, but unless you're using the [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) or [apd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) extensions (or similar) you can't rename or remove functions

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your function within a "function_exists" check :

```
if (!function_exists('my_func')){

  function my_func(){
    //...
  }

}
```

you can find more details here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.function-exists.php