# How can disable default php function in some specific page?

Tags: php, security

I know i can use disable_functions directive in php.ini configuration file to disable some default PHP function (for example fopen(), rename, ftp_chdir()……..) in whole website.

```
disable_functions
disable_functions =”function a, function b, …………. function (n)”
```

There is a question, if i want some function can run in a.php but cannot run in b.php and c.php , that mean i want to block the function just in some specific page, how can i do it?

Comment: Build the function into a class and make it a private function. Then it can only be called from its class.

Comment: @Geohut How to build default PHP function (for example fopen(), rename, ftp_chdir()……..)  in a class?

Comment: follow OOPS.. You will have identifiers public, private using that you can control the stuffs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a function at runtime in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120044/removing-a-function-at-runtime-in-php)

Comment: @paul9508 oh you are trying to limit a default php command to a certain file. There really isn't a way to do that.  There really isn't a need to limit those functions, but you could wrap the function in a class function and only call it from that class, but that still won't stop those default functions from being able to be executed outside. You can remove the function from core php like you said and rewrite the function from within a class would be your main option you can look at the php source code online for the function.

Comment: This is a security problem. For example, i want to disable the function fopen() in b.php , if b.php try to run fopen() , it will be stop.

Comment: @Geohut This is a security problem. For example, i want to disable the function fopen() in b.php , if b.php try to run fopen() , it will be stop. In the case b.php will not include fopen() originally, but some reason if the code in b.php change by another people and try to run fopen() , the php file can stop it. This like using disable_functions , but i want just some php file will disable fopen() bceause another php file will use fopen().

Comment: No one should have access to run commands like that on the server unless they have proper access to the server. No one on the front end can just come in and run fopen.