# Require once wp-load appear error cannot redeclare function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have script

```
<?php
require('../../wp-load.php');
function tes_aaa(){
  echo 'aaa';
}

tes_aaa();
?>
```

But it gives me an error

> Cannot redeclare tes_aaa() (previously declared in

If I remove wp-load it's works. Why?  I made an application in wordpress plugin. I need to work with databse and want to use `$wpdb` class so I inlcude wp-load.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing a function at runtime in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120044/removing-a-function-at-runtime-in-php)

Comment: Hi, I've edited your post to improve grammar and formatting; it seems that the error message is not complete, can you fix it? Are you sure that `tes_aaa` is not defined in wp-load.php?

Comment: are you using this code within loop?

Comment: No. I have change name the function again but still got same error.

Comment: I change anything name in function got error cannot redeclare

Comment: Hi @NovarliSiradjuddin, You found any solution I got the same issue.

Comment: I answered this same questions here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93960/wp-load-php-redeclares-classes/391563#391563